# PLSql: Error when updating a table with a trigger conflict

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to update the status of a value in a table but the table has an associated trigger with a not  null condition, it is throwing an error ORA-01400 error.

```
UPDATE ***** SET IND_VALID='0' WHERE ***** IN ('330534');
```

This is the trigger code

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER "*******"."TIDUA_ECHANTFCE" 
 AFTER
 INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
 ON MASTERCA.ECHANTFCE  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
declare
 seq_id integer;
 change_reason varchar2(4000);
 login varchar2(250);
 Version varchar2(80);
begin

 Version := 'AUDIT_TRAIL V1.0 / SPEC : xxxxxx v xx';
  change_reason := system.AUDTRAIL_CHGREASON.get_change_reason();
  login := system.connectionpool.get_user_login();
  select seq_audit_trail.nextval into seq_id from dual;

if UPDATING then
    insert into audtrailrow (audit_trail_row_id,table_name, data_row_id, change_type, user_login,
      change_dt, change_reason_value)
      values (seq_id, 'ECHANTFCE', :new.ID_ECHANT_FCE, 'U', login, sysdate, change_reason);
```

Comment: It seems the error is thrown by the trigger. You need to post the trigger code if you hope for us to help you.

Comment: ORA-01400: cannot insert null into (string) is a specific error to the null value in Oracle. According to Oracle, a null value can appear in columns of any datatype as long as it is not set to the value “not null” or is restricted by primary key integrity constraints. can you share all the code !!!